# How to read float from binary file using Tcl_ReadChars?

Tags: c, tcl

The preferred method for reading from a channel using the Tcl API is `Tcl_ReadChars()`. When reading from a binary channel, the data will be stored as a byte array until referenced, at which point conversions will be done.

I then have a set of functions for retrieving data from the object: `Tcl_Get{String,Double,Int}FromObj()`. However, if I read in a float, it seems that none of these will do the right thing to extract the value I intended.

At this point, I am trying to reason from the documentation. It may be the case that `Tcl_GetDoubleFromObj()` will be flexible enough to handle this case... but that doesn't seem to be the case based on the documentation.

Using the Tcl C API, how should I read a float from a binary file?

Comment: At the C level? Get the bytes and directly cast them. That's what the `binary` command does. (`Tcl_GetDoubleFromObj` parses a human-readable string.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't swear this is the source of the implementation of your `Tcl_GetDoubleFromOjb()`, but it looks like it might be a version of it:   http://tclsrc.tyabo.com/tclObj_8c-source.html

It doesn't look like it's doing a straight conversion of a raw double.   It looks like it's pulling a double from a TCL created object, not a stream of raw bytes.

Maybe you want to look into `binary scan` as a way of pulling the floats/doubles out of your binary stream?

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to binary scan. Although if the solution involves hacking at the internals of the Tcl_Obj, then it's probably better to just read the data without using the Tcl  API at all.

Comment: I think `binary scan` is part of the TCL language.  No need to hack anything.   I was just showing the implementation of `Tcl_GetDoubleFromObj()` to point out it might not be what you're looking for.

Comment: Ah, sorry, my mistake. I'm still feeling my way around these tools. The more I've read and experimented over the course of the night, I'm pretty sure that I'm asking for something that has a lot more hidden complexity than I thought at first. Thanks for helping out!